# Nav items are not aligned in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My navitems are taking up two lines when I shrink my screen to mobile view. The search bar and hamburger menu and the logo are all in different places, I want them in a single line.

mobile view:

[image]

desktop view:

[image]
Any input will be appriciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="images/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="images/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="images/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="images/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="images/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="images/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Rento</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="logo rounded ms-1" src="images/logo.jpeg" alt="Rento" width="70" height="70" >
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-11 mx-auto my-auto search-box">
      <div class="input-group form-container">
        <input class="form-control search-input" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria- 
 label="Search" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" name="button">Search</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Signin</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Cart</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I change `col-11` to `col-6` for search-box.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-6 mx-auto my-auto search-box">
```

so in this case you can use `col-6` in all devices.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/apple-icon-57x57.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="images/apple-icon-60x60.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="images/apple-icon-76x76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-icon-114x114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="images/apple-icon-120x120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/apple-icon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/apple-icon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/apple-icon-180x180.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="images/android-icon-192x192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="images/favicon-96x96.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="images/manifest.json">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/ms-icon-144x144.png">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Rento</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="logo rounded ms-1" src="images/logo.jpeg" alt="Rento" width="70" height="70">
    </a>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-6 mx-auto my-auto search-box">
      <div class="input-group form-container">
        <input class="form-control search-input" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria- label="Search" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" name="button">Search</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Signin</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Cart</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the length of your search tab is large.To align the elements in a single line adjust the size of the search tab. This would help with this issue. Here I have just provided the code for your reference

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="images/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="images/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="images/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="images/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="images/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="images/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Rento</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="logo rounded ms-1" src="images/logo.jpeg" alt="Rento" width="70" height="70" >
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-5 mx-auto my-auto search-box">
      <div class="input-group form-container">
        <input class="form-control search-input" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria- 
 label="Search" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" name="button">Search</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Signin</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Cart</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```